# Что это за запись с typedef?

Tags: c++, типы, typedef

```
typedef int(_stdcall*_MessageboxA)(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT);
```

Я не могу понять,что тут переопределяется?Помогите расшифровать данную строку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Определяется `_MessageboxA` как псевдоним для типа указателя на функцию с аргументами `HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT`, возвращающую `int` и с соглашениями о вызове `_stdcall`.

А теперь подробнее. Как выглядит функция?

```
int Function(.....); // .... - аргументы
```

Чтобы описать указатель на функцию, недостаточно написать

```
int *Function(.....);
```

Так это будет функция, возвращающая `int*`, так что нужны вторые скобки:

```
int (*Function)(.....);
```

Так понятнее?

Comment: Скобки расставлены непонятным образом,очень сложно понять что к чему

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение,но не понятно как в данном случае работает typedef ,что на что она будет заменять.

Comment: Она ничего ни на что не меняет. Она создает новое имя для типа. Например, `typedef int I;` - после этого `I i;` эквивалентно `int i;`. Теперь у вас есть тип `_MessageboxA`. См., например, https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef